# Group homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_p\to G$ are bijective to the set of elements of order $1$ or $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are the group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to G$ in bijection with the set of elements of $G$ that have order $1$ or $p$?

What I know:

- The elements of order 1 or p are mapped to the elements of order 1 or p under group homomorphisms (since they are roots of $t^p=1$; so $1=f(1)=f(t^p)=f(t)^p$)
- If we have a homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to G$, then it is determined by $f(1)$. And since 1 has order p, $f(1)$ must have order 1 or p.

I think what remains to show is that whenever a map $f$ is such that $f(1)$ has order 1 or p, $f$ is actually a group homomorphism, right? How to show that?

---

Updated version:

We need to construct a bijection $$(\text{grp homos } \mathbb Z_p\to H)\leftrightarrow \text{elts of } H \text{ of order dividing } p$$

Assign to a group homo $f:\mathbb Z_p\to H$, the element $f(\overline 1)$. Call this assignment $F$.

In the other direction, assign to an element $x$ of order dividing $p$ the homomorphism given by $f(\overline n)=x^n$. Call this assignment $G$. Note that $G(x)$ is well-defined: suppose $\overline m=\overline n$ so that $m-n\in p \mathbb Z$ (i.e., $m=n+pk$ for $k$ an integer). Then $f(\overline m)=x^{n+pk}=x^nx^{pk}=x^n=f(\overline n)$.

It remains to check that the compositions $F\circ G$ and $G\circ F$ are identities.

- $F(G(x))=F(\overline n\mapsto x^n)=x^1=x$, so $F\circ G=id$
- $G(F(\phi:\mathbb Z_p\to G))=G(\phi(\overline 1))=(\overline n\mapsto \phi(\overline 1)^n)$, so $G\circ F=id$

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Do you know how to define maps out of a quotient $G/H$ ?

Comment: @Max If you mean the statement that it's enough to define a homomorphism from $G$ and check that all elements of $H$ map to zero, then yes.

Comment: The statement in your final paragraph is wrong, because $f(2)$ depends on $f(1)$. In fact it contradicts your second bullet point, which is right.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why does it contradict the second bullet point? I don't see how the dependence of $f(2)$ on $f(1)$ helps. And if the last paragraph is wrong, is the original statement wrong too?

Comment: Then since $\mathbb{Z/pZ}$ is a quotient of $\mathbb Z$ you should be able to define maps out of it : do you know how to define maps out of $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: @Max To define a group homo out of $\mathbb Z$, we just need to send $1$ anywhere. If additionally all multiples of $p$ get send to zero, then this induces a group homo out of $\mathbb Z_p$. But for now I can't quite relate this to what we need. Especially after Derek Holt's comment.

Comment: Well if $x$ has order $1$ or $p$, does $f: n\mapsto x^n$ (defined on $\mathbb Z$) have the required property ? (I think Derek was mostly worried about your formulation : if $f$ is *any* function such that $f(1)$ has order $1$ or $p$ it does not follow that it is a morphism, $f$ needs to be of the appropriate form, which you implicitly stated, but Derek (probably) wanted to make sure you were clear on what you meant)

Comment: @Max I've updated my question to make it more precise. I don't think I used that "classification" of maps out of the quotient.

Comment: You miswrote the value of $G(\phi(1))$

Comment: @Max Is it correct now? And there is no need to use that classification, right?

Comment: Well there is, to define $G$

Comment: @Max How is it used in the definition of $G$? We are directly defining $G(x)$ to be the map $\mathbb Z_p\to H, \overline n\mapsto x^n$. And the latter map is a homo because $\phi(\overline m+\overline n)=\phi(\overline{m+n})=x^{m+n}=x^mx^n=\phi(\overline m)\phi(\overline n)$.

Comment: Well first of all you need to show that $G(x)$ is *well-defined*. Doing that *and* checking it is a morphism is just reproving the criterion

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Since every element $g$ of the group $\Bbb Z_p$ has order $1$ or $p$, $\varphi (g)^p=\varphi (g^p)=\varphi (e)=e$.  Thus the order of $\varphi (g)$ divides $p$.

On the other hand,  we are free to send any generator of $\Bbb Z_p$ to any such element,  and this will determine a homomorphism.

A choice of $\varphi (1)\in G$ will determine each homomorphism.  And since $\langle 1\rangle =\Bbb Z_p$, the homomorphism is given by $\varphi (n)=\varphi (1)^n$ for each $n\in \Bbb Z_p$.

Since the only subgroups of $\Bbb Z_p$ are the identity and itself,  any homomorphism from it will be an embedding or the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: I thought we need to show that any map of sets $\mathbb Z_p\to G$ that sends $\overline 1$ to an element of order $p$ is a group homomorphism. Is it obvious?

Comment: It is not obvious because it is wrong.